# REST API call from Excel VBA: request header not being sent

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, xmlhttprequest

I'm freaking out to make a simple api call from Excel, I tried all the below different ways but the request token is never sent, therefore it fails.

For both **method 1 and 2**, I get the following error message:

[image]

For **method 3** I get a timeout error so maybe it works but I need to specify somehow a longer timeout threshold...and I do not know how...

Can somebody help me please?

**Method 1**

```
Sub test()
Debug.Print "Running..."
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim XMLHTTP As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, myurl As String
Dim token As String
Dim content_type As String

token = [...omissis...]
content_type = "application/json"


myurl = [...omissis...]
'xmlhttp.Open "GET", myurl, False
'xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "X-Auth-Token", [...omissis...]
'xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
'xmlhttp.send

With XMLHTTP
    .Open "GET", myurl, False
    .setRequestHeader "X-Auth-Token", token
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", content_type
    .send
End With
Debug.Print "Response header Cookie: "
MsgBox (XMLHTTP.responseText)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

**Method 2**

```
Sub httpPost()
Dim XMLHTTP
Dim result As String

Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
XMLHTTP.Open "GET", _
"[...omissis...]", False
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-Auth-Token", [...omissis...]
XMLHTTP.send
result = XMLHTTP.responseText
Debug.Print result
Set XMLHTTP = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Method 3**

```
Private Sub cmdKirimGET_Click()
    Dim strResult As String
    Dim objHTTP As Object
    Dim URL As String
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    URL = [...omissis...]
    objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-Auth-Token", [...omissis...]
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
    objHTTP.send
    strResult = objHTTP.responseText
    Debug.Print strResult
    'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A10:A10") = strResult
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

it might be helpful to know which API you are calling. I'm calling various APIs in my excel project: https://github.com/krijnsent/crypto_vba -> see **modWeb.bas** for my GET/POST commands. Tests are at the top of the module.

It's probably easiest to download **crypto_vba_example.xlsm** , which has the right references. Hope that works.